# invert Y scale in rastervis R

Tags: raster, r, levelplot

I want to make a hovmoller diagram; I want to change the order of Y axis (to start with 2010 - on bottom and finish 1970 - to be on top:

```
library(zoo)
library(rasterVis)
library(raster)

download.file('http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/SOURCES/.CAC/.sst/data.nc', 
              destfile = 'SST.nc') # here you can find the data (about 3,9 MO size)

SST <- brick('data.nc')
idx <- seq(as.Date('1970-01-01'), as.Date('2003-03-01'), by='month')
tt <- as.yearmon(idx)
SST <- setZ(SST, tt)
names(SST) <- as.character(tt)


hovmoller(SST,
          panel = panel.levelplot.raster,
          interpolate = TRUE,
          yscale.components = yscale.raster.subticks,
          par.settings = BuRdTheme)
```

So I need to have 1970 on top of the graph instead of 2010. Anyone can offer some help please?

Comment: you download the file as `SST.nc` but read in `data.nc` - edit?

Comment: It looks like if the Z values are numeric or "yearmon" then it will always plot sorted numerically that way. If you set the Z values to character then its plotted in the order of the layers, but in this case the X axis gets 399 overlapping unreadable labels...

Comment: @Spacedman - yes, I downloaded the wrong file (I copied the example from rasterVis help page). sorry for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this. First reverse the order of layers in `SST` into `SSTR`:

```
> SSTR = SST[[nlayers(SST):1]]
```

Then set the Z for `SSTR` as the reverse of `SST`, and convert to character so that `hovmoller` doesn't go and sort it back again for us:

```
> SSTR= setZ(SSTR, rev(as.character(getZ(SST))))
```

Next plot but only label the Y axis every two years, starting from the first January:

```
> hovmoller(SSTR, scales=list(y=list(at=seq(3, nlayers(SSTR),by=24))))
```

[image]

Please check carefully that this is all right before using it in anger. It looks different to `hovmoller(SST)` but there may be a bunch of other reasons for that! I have tried some tests on tiny raster stacks so I'm fairly confident...

Comment: Many thanks, great idea! Is working with my data so I am pretty sure that your suggestion is good.